# Outputlink's value with If statement

Tags: visualforce, outputlink

Within my Wrapper Contact's list, I do have Contact records without Accounts. I wanted to have a condition such that the account label is clickable only when there is an Account to that Contact record. Here is what I have implemented, which gets me an error

```
<apex:column headerValue="Account">
    <apex:outputLink target="_parent" value="{!If(NOT(ISNULL(URLFOR($Action.Account.View, c.actId))), URLFOR($Action.Account.View, c.actId), '#')}" >
          {!c.accName}
    </apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>
```

Error:

> *Content cannot be displayed: Invalid parameter for function URLFOR*

**Note:** Only few contacts have the AccountIds as null. 
Where am I doing wrong?

Refernced [this link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18754/display-link-depending-on-value-in-a-visualforce-page) before posting.

Comment: FYI just use `BLANKVALUE`. That said, what is the variable type for `actId`? I don't think `String` will work, it has to be `Id`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, actId is of variable type Id. Also having BLANKVALUE without the # symbol, gets me the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking whether the `URLFOR()` function returns `null`, conditionally render the whole component by wrapping it in an `<apex:outputPanel>`.

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{! NOT(ISBLANK(c.actId)) }">
    <apex:outputLink value="{! URLFOR($Action.Account.View, c.actId) }" ...>
    ...
</apex:outputPanel>
```

That way you won't try to render components that don't make sense or cannot be evaluated with a `null` Id value (it's passing a `null` Id to `URLFOR()` that's generating this error, since it gets evaluated inside your `IF()` even if its result isn't used).

Comment: Previously I wasn't aware that the URLFOR is being evaluated even without any accountId. That makes real sense for the error.